# Conclusions From a Junior School Science Experiment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, ideal-gas

If you stick a tissue to the bottom of a glass and immerse this glass fully (upside down) into a tumbler of water, then this tissue remains dry. Why is this so? / What conclusion would you draw from this?

a) Air occupies a definite volume.

b) Air has mass.

c) Both

Now, I think it should be both. Reason:

If air had a volume but zero mass (hypothetically speaking), then it will not exert any pressure, so therefore water would rise till it hits the tissue (pressure due to air is the reason water level is lower, right?)!

Also, we can say that if an object has zero mass, we can have 100 % compressibility for any definite volume.

Pls tell me if my approach is right?

PS: I am not in junior school, my sister is, and this is from her weekly test.

Comment: Note that photons are massless but exert pressure. And I think that the question is rather subjective, a possible conclusion could be that the tissue is hydrophobic.

Comment: In fact, you could draw any conclusion you want, even if it's wrong. For example, option a) is not very precise, since it ignores compressibility.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with questions like this is that they depend on your level of knowledge.  My intuition is that the answer is A considering this is a question at the Junior Highschool level.  The reasoning for A is because we see that the air inside the glass prevents the water from entering it (i.e. air occupies a volume).

However, you have put serious thought into the answer C and I'd like to bring up some issues with your reasoning (though I do think that at a highschool/college level understanding of physics, C is correct).

First, remember that collisions (and thus pressure and compressiblity) are fundamentally due to electrostatic repulsion and not mass.  Though, if we look at Newton's Second Law $F=ma$ we see that if there is an electrostatic force on a massless particle, it seems like the acceleration would be infinite and thus we already find a problem in dealing with massless things.  Since the atoms of air clearly don't suddenly appear to have infinite velocity, we could conclude that they have mass.

We can also consider an elementary knowledge of temperature as the average kinetic energy of the particles.  Since kinetic energy is proportional to mass, we then expect massless particles to have zero temperature.  But we know this not to be true simply because we live in air.

There are many other reasoning for air having mass.  But, I don't think any of them directly have to do with the experiment and probably are not at the level of understanding that the question is asked from.

Lastly, as a side note, the properties of massless things are not described using the techniques I used above (e.g. Newton's Laws, Average Kinetic Energy, etc...).  One shouldn't attempt to make any serious conclusions from that analysis.  I just wanted to point out how one might think about massless objects at a highschool physics level of understanding.

Comment: Thanks for giving a broader perspective to this. You are right, I am at high school sophomore level. Now, when I thought about pressure, I visualized collisions with the walls of a container acc to Kinetic Theory Of Gases (Not applicable for massless "air"), but then the question was, does this experiment prove air has mass? It wasnt "Is this an experiment you would *use to prove that air has mass*.?" I think the difference will change the answer

Comment: If we ignore what we already know about air form everday life, then this experiment cannot prove air has mass.  All it proves is that 1) air cannot move through glass and 2) air cannot move through water.  However, we are asked to answer the question in the context of the class and the given answers.  Whenever confronted with multiple choice questions, it is always best to answer what you think the teacher wants.  Often, multiple choice questions are not worded perfectly and if you think too deeply you'll end up tripping over yourself.

Comment: I couldnt agree more with the last 3 lines, however, when you say everyday life, do you mean intuition? If so, I am not sure that is the way we predict hypothetical cases. I only thought of the theories I have studied in physics and chemistry that deal with gases

Comment: By everyday life, I meant our experiences with air outside of the experiment.